# Google Sheet App Script: Match two values from one sheet to another sheet and then set a value if they match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

very new to app script but well versed in formulas and so up-skilling.

For reference I've made a test sheet [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rXnWQBD9OS0mf-wIJpU9FGV93oUdfAqnfKCrQiXB640/edit?usp=sharing)

My script has been a Frankenstein of tutorials but essentially I'm trying to match the name and date from sheet 2 to the data in sheet 1 and if they match then in column "C" I'd like to setValue as "sent"

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
    function sendReport() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var clientName = ss.getRange ("Sheet2!B1");
  var testDate = ss.getRange ("Sheet2!B2")
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = destSheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++){

    if (values[i][1] == clientName
        && values[i][2] == testDate) {
      values[i][3] = Yes; 
}
range.setValues(values)
  }
```

The actual sheet is quite large and it seems to go through each row at a time checking as the script takes a long time to run but then it's not adding the "Yes" value into the column to confirm the report has been sent.

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following script

```js
function sendReport() {
  Logger.log("Starting script...");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // you need to get the actual sheets of the array
  // you can use array destructuring (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for this
  const [sheet1, sheet2] = ss.getSheets(); // getSheets() returns an array of sheets
  // get ranges from sheet 2
  // no need to provide the sheet name as a parameter, because we're calling it on sheet2 already
  const clientName = sheet2.getRange("B1").getDisplayValue(); // you need to get the display value, not just the range
  const testDate = sheet2.getRange("B2").getDisplayValue(); 

  // start in row 2, column 1 and get all rows expect the first (=> last - 1) and get 3 columns
  const range = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1, 2);
  // use forEach() and array destructuring again here. 
  // the second parameter idx is a zero-based index we need to set the value of column sent 
  range.getDisplayValues().forEach(([name, date, sent], idx) => {
    // Use JavaScript strict comparison with === instead of ==
    // check if name and date match and sent is not already set to "sent"
    Logger.log(`Comparing name ${name} with ${clientName} and date ${date} with ${testDate}...`);
    if(name === clientName && date === testDate && sent !== "sent") {
      // we need to use idx + 2 because line 1 is the heading and idx of forEach() is zero-based but Spreadsheet API is one-based
      Logger.log(`Ìn row ${idx + 2} name and date match! Setting "sent"...`);
      sheet1.getRange(idx + 2, 3).setValue("sent");
    }
  })
  // set value "report sent" on sheet2  to "sent"
  sheet2.getRange("B3").setValue("sent")
  Logger.log("Report sent.")
}
```

Some pointers on your code.

- You need to get actual values using `getValue()` or `getDisplayValue()` on a `Range` in order to obtain the values.
- You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which will be more convenient and more readable than dealing with indices all the time
- You should use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or other JavaScript array methods to iterate over arrays
- JavaScript has multiple comparison operators. You should use the [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) `===` whenever possible as this also takes data types into account in contrast to the [normal equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) `==`
- You can use `Logger.log()` to print something to the console while the script is executing
- Try to use `const` variables every time you are not planning to change the value of a variable instead of `var`. It is considered best practice to not change values at all but instead treat them as [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) as this avoids a lot of errors.

##### Inputs

###### Input in Sheet1

I have changed one row (in my copy of your Spreadsheet) so that one element actually fullfills the condition and is updated.

[image: Sheet 1 input]

###### Input in Sheet2

[image: Sheet 2 input]

##### Result

###### Output Sheet1

[image: Sheet 1 output]

###### Output Sheet2

[image: Sheet 2 output]

Comment: Thank you so much for going into such detail. Works perfectly, took a little bit of time to take it from the simple test sheet into the real thing but it's working great. Thank you again. I'm an exercise physiologist and maximised what formulas can do for me at the moment and the need for code is upon me.